# How to download multiple numbered images from a website in an easy manner?

Tags: download, wget, browser-addons

I'd like to download multiple numbered images from a website.

The images are structured like this:

```
http://website.com/images/foo1bar.jpg

http://website.com/images/foo2bar.jpg

http://website.com/images/foo3bar.jpg
```

... And I'd like to download all of the images within a specific interval.

Are there simple browser addons that could do this, or should I use "wget" or the like?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You know how to use wget, you must know how to use shell scripts :)

Comment: Oh. I don't know how to use wget or shell scripts. Just saw it being mentioned when I looked for a way to do what I want to do. :)

Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Crudely, on Unix-like systems:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in {1..3}
do
    wget http://website.com/images/foo"$i"bar.jpg
done
```

Try googling "bash for loop".

**Edit** LOL! Indeed, in a haste I omitted the name of the very program that downloads the image files. Also, this goes into a text editor, then you save it with an arbitrary file name, make it executable with the command

```
chmod u+x the_file_name
```

and finally you run it with

```
./the_file_name
```