# How to automatize multiple (30143) images downloading from a website

Tags: python, automation, download

There is a website that stores two videos as a list of thousands of PNGs, 31145 images in total. Is there a way to automate the downloading by generating the URLs? (I have no knowledge in coding.)

1. Here's the 1st video's [first frame](https://cf-images.eu-west-1.prod.boltdns.net/v1/jit/719509184001/570e9336-d36c-4d41-8cbe-a67fe3bdc2b6/main/1280x720/00000ms/match/image.png) and its [last frame](https://cf-images.eu-west-1.prod.boltdns.net/v1/jit/719509184001/570e9336-d36c-4d41-8cbe-a67fe3bdc2b6/main/1280x720/19999ms/match/image.png).
2. Here's the 2nd video's [first frame](https://cf-images.eu-west-1.prod.boltdns.net/v1/jit/719509184001/e23d962c-114b-40ed-b934-667f77482f8e/main/1280x720/00000ms/match/image.png) and its [last frame](https://cf-images.eu-west-1.prod.boltdns.net/v1/jit/719509184001/e23d962c-114b-40ed-b934-667f77482f8e/main/1280x720/11144ms/match/image.png).

---

I couldn't access the directory and batch download the files.

I took a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854036/how-to-download-multiple-numbered-images-from-a-website-in-an-easy-manner) but it doesn't apply to me as I use Windows 10, and also checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop); I tried to merge them into `for /l %x in (1, 1, 19999) do (wget https://cf-images.eu-west-1.prod.boltdns.net/v1/jit/719509184001/570e9336-d36c-4d41-8cbe-a67fe3bdc2b6/main/1280x720/%%xms/match/image.png)` which did not work obviously.

I then downloaded Python 3.11 to try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324672/downloading-a-list-of-files-from-a-website) but doesn't work, it's probably too old as it tells me urllib2 doesn't exist.

Comment: A frame every 1ms would mean a picture repeat rate of 1000/s (1000Hz). I would expect a "video" frame rate to be between 20 and 60 Hz. So that might explain those "frame duplicates". It might be enough to download each 16th to 50th frame.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On Python 3.11 for Windows 10 64-bit

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
template_url = 'https://cf-images.eu-west-1.prod.boltdns.net/v1/jit/719509184001/570e9336-d36c-4d41-8cbe-a67fe3bdc2b6/main/1280x720/%05dms/match/image.png'
template_name = 'image%05d.png'
for i in range(0,20000):
    f = template_name % i
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(template_url % i, f)
```

---

It is very slow, it took me at least 5 hours to download everything as it does it 1-by-1 and sometimes stops working (due to the website) and doesn't restart automatically. And almost 80% of the images downloaded are duplicates so it's extremely unpractical (7 Go). And all the images are downloaded to a temp folder. But the code works! I believe it was made to replicate Minecraft but in software like After Effects so all the frames are just a teeny tiny bit different from each other...

---

Sources: Python [1](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve)
[2](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) [3](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) [4](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html) [5](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-201/#locations) ; Stackoverflow [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854036/how-to-download-multiple-numbered-images-from-a-website-in-an-easy-manner) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324672/downloading-a-list-of-files-from-a-website) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760728/python-3-urllib-produces-typeerror-post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of) ; and @Daweo's help

Answer (score 1):

You need to get two things: generate URLs of images, then download them.

Generating URLs can be done using for loop and formatting, consider following simple example

```
template = 'xxx/%05dms/match/image.png'
for i in range(1,11): # limited for brevity sake, adjust as requires
    print(template % i)
```

gives output

```
xxx/00001ms/match/image.png
xxx/00002ms/match/image.png
xxx/00003ms/match/image.png
xxx/00004ms/match/image.png
xxx/00005ms/match/image.png
xxx/00006ms/match/image.png
xxx/00007ms/match/image.png
xxx/00008ms/match/image.png
xxx/00009ms/match/image.png
xxx/00010ms/match/image.png
```

`%05d` denotes put decimal number here, prefixed by zeros to width of 5 characters.

For downloading you might use [`urllib.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) rembering to furnish unique names, consider following simple example

```
import urllib
template_url = 'xxx/%05dms/match/image.png'
template_name = 'image%05d.png'
for i in range(1,11):
    urllib.urlretrieve(template_url % i, template_name % i)
```

which after you set template_url to real one should download images to current working directory as `image00001.png` and so on.

Note: as you are using `xrange` I assume you must use `python2` AT ANY PRICE, thus I use `urllib.urlretrieve` rather than `urllib.request.urlretrieve` and ancient method of string formatting rather than so-called f-strings.

Comment: I'm already impressed that the url generation works, however when I tried running the full code it doesn't work.
I tried on Python 3.11 then I saw you mention Python2 so I tried installing Python 2.0 but Windows said no, so I tried with Python 2.7 and it replied `IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:140773E8:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1000)`

Comment: I don't know what happened, nor why. I tried things and this seems to work (somewhat):

`import urllib
import urllib.request
template_url = 'https://cf-images.eu-west-1.prod.boltdns.net/v1/jit/719509184001/570e9336-d36c-4d41-8cbe-a67fe3bdc2b6/main/1280x720/%05dms/match/image.png'
template_name = 'image%05d.png'
for i in range(1,11):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(template_url % i, data=None)`

- Problem 1: files are saved on a temp folder with lots of other random stuff
- Problem 2: files are not named in a practical way and have no .png extension